# ProgressBar acting weird, running twice

Tags: c#, visual-studio, progress-bar

I am new to c#, but am well versed in Python, this is only my second program i have made in c#, the first was the classic 'hello world' program. i am a student. i have already run into trouble.

here is what i am trying to do:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;

        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;

        for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = i;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        label2.Visible = true;
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

but for some reason the progressbar performs two cycles before showing the completion message. i am stumped as to why and how to fix it.

thank you in advance!

Comment: You're blocking the UI thread. Don't do that, basically. You should read up on how Windows Forms deals with threading.

Comment: Use application.DoEvents to allow the form to update the progress bar. But it doesn't explain  why it performs twice... Maybe just an illusion :-)

Comment: I'm guessing that button1_Click is called twice, maybe you are assigning it from class code and from designer.

Comment: Use of `Application.DoEvents` is a _bad_ idea.  Don't do it.